# keras.layers.TimeDistributed with hub.KerasLayer NotImplementedError

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I want to use tf.keras.TimeDistributed() layer with the tf.hub inception_v3 CNN model from the latest TensorFLow V2 version (tf-nightly-gpu-2.0-preview). The output is shown below. It seemst that tf.keras.TimeDistributed() is not fully implemented to work with tf.hub models. Somehow, the shape of the input layer cannot be computed. My question: Is there a workaround this problem?

tf.keras.TimeDistributed with regular tf.keras.layer works fine. I just would like to apply the CNN model to each time step.

#### Model

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub 
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model

model_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-
```

preview/inception_v3/feature_vector/3"

```
feature_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model_url,
                               input_shape = (299, 299, 3),
                               output_shape = [2048],
                               trainable = False)

video = layers.Input(shape = (None, 299, 299, 3))

encoded_frames = layers.TimeDistributed(feature_layer)(video)

model = Model(inputs = video, outputs = encoded_frames)
```

#### Expected output

tf.keras model

#### Error messages

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 489, in compute_output_shape
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError

Answer (score 1):

Wrapper Layers like `TimeDistributed` require a `layer` instance to be passed.   If you build the model out of custom  layers, you'll need to at least wrap them in `tf.keras.layers.Lambda`.   This might not be possible in your case of models from `hub.KerasLayer`, so you might consider the solutions posted here:

[TimeDistributed of a KerasLayer in Tensorflow 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59970196/timedistributed-of-a-keraslayer-in-tensorflow-2-0)

Answer (score 1):

In Tensorflow 2 it is possible to use custom layers in combination with the `TimeDistributed` layer. The error is thrown because it can't compute the output shape (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L741)).

So in your case you should be able to subclass `KerasLayer` and implement `compute_output_shape` manually.