# TimeDistributed of a KerasLayer in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer, tensorflow-hub

I'm trying to build a CNN + RNN using a pre-trained model from tensorflow-hub:

```
base_model = hub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v2_50/feature_vector/4', input_shape=(244, 244, 3)
base_model.trainable = False

model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(base_model, input_shape=(15, 244, 244, 3)))
model.add(LSTM(512))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

adam = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer=adam , metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

and this what I get:

2020-01-29 16:1

```
6:37.585888: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2494000000 Hz
2020-01-29 16:16:37.586205: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x3b553f0 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2020-01-29 16:16:37.586231: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./RNN.py", line 45, in <module>
    model.add(TimeDistributed(base_model, input_shape=(None, 244, 244, 3)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 178, in add
    layer(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 842, in __call__
    outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/wrappers.py", line 256, in call
    output_shape = self.compute_output_shape(input_shape).as_list()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/wrappers.py", line 210, in compute_output_shape
    child_output_shape = self.layer.compute_output_shape(child_input_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 639, in compute_output_shape
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

any suggestions?
Is it possible to convert a KerasLayer to Conv2D,... layers?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem like you can use the `TimeDistributed` layer for this problem. However, as you don't want Resnet to train and just need the output, you can do the following to avoid the `TimeDistributed` layer.

Instead of  `model.add(TimeDistributed(base_model, input_shape=(15, 244, 244, 3)))`, do

### Option 1

```
# 2048 is the output size
model.add(
    Lambda(
        lambda x: tf.reshape(base_model(tf.reshape(x, [-1, 244, 244,3])),[-1, 15, 2048])
    , input_shape=(15, 244, 244, 3))
)
```

### Option 2

If you don't want to depend too much on the output shape (this sacrifices performance though).

```
model.add(
    Lambda(
        lambda x: tf.stack([base_model(xx) for xx in tf.unstack(x, axis=1) ], axis=1)
    , input_shape=(15, 244, 244, 3))
)
```

Comment: I think TimeDistributed and LSTM layers are nedded because I have sequences of 15 frames to classify. I noticed that if I use KerasLayer for a pretrained model from Tensorflow Hub it give me that error, if I define a ResNet50 from tf.keras.applications.ResNet50 it don't give me any error. What is the difference? I don't understand

Comment: Your `KerasLayer` doesn't need to go through a `TimeDistributed` layer. All it's doing is giving a feature vector for each image and it's not optimized (the layer is frozen). It doesn't matter if you process the data with or without a timestep for the Resnet part.

Comment: And for the different `tf_hub` is different from `tf.keras.applications`. Models in `tf.keras.applications` are well integrated to `tf.keras` operations. Whereas `tf_hub` might not.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for explanation. So it is not possible tu use a pre trained network for transfering learning to a CNN+RNN convolutional layer?

Comment: @NickF_93 Unfortunately I don't see a way. I got the same error as you and couldn't get around it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I also tried to use `tf.keras.applications` but I have the problem described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58607878/tensorflow-hub-vs-keras-application-performance-drop and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59994205/keraslayer-vs-tf-keras-applications-performances .

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56173992/keras-layers-timedistributed-with-hub-keraslayer-notimplementederror/63582596#63582596). The error is thrown because it can't compute the output shape, you might be able to solve your problem by implementing `compute_output_shape` manually.

Answer (score 0):

If someone faces this issue, as @josef mentioned, the problem is that `compute_output_shape` is not implemented. You can overcome the problem by specifying the output shape of the layer:

```
extractor = tfhub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_100_224/feature_vector/4",
                              input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, CHANNELS),
                              output_shape=(EXTRACTOR_SIZE),
                              trainable=False)
    
model.add(keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: extractor(x)))
```

As you can see, I also had to wrap the layer inside of a `Lambda` function since it looks like you can't wrap `KerasLayer` directly inside of a `TimeDistributed` layer.

In the code, `EXTRACTOR_SIZE` is `1280` but that is specific of `MobileNet`.

This workaround worked for me.