# KerasLayer vs tf.keras.applications performances

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tf.keras, transfer-learning

I've trained some networks with ResNetV2 50 ( https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v2_50/feature_vector/4 ) and it work very well for my datasets.

Then I tried `tf.keras.applications.ResNet50` and accuracy is very lower than the other.

Here two models:

The first (with hub)

```
base_model = hub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v2_50/feature_vector/4', input_shape=(IMAGE_H, IMAGE_W, 3))
base_model.trainable = False

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  base_model ,
  Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
])
```

The second (with keras.applications)

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50V2(input_shape=(IMAGE_H, IMAGE_W, 3), include_top=False, weights='imagenet', pooling='avg')
base_model.trainable = False

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  base_model,
  Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
])
```

The optimizer is the same (Adam), epochs, steps, dataset (train and validation), learning rate are the same as well. But the first start with a val_accuracy near 80% and end with an accuracy near 99%, the second start with 85% of val_accuracy from first to last epoch, as it's overfitting. I got the same behavior changing dataset and parameters for each model.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The model retrieved from `tfhub` is hosted by Google and comes from the TF-Slim implementation. Whereas the `tf.keras.applications.ResNet50V2` downloads its weights from `fchollet` GitHub repo. Maybe the models would have been trained on different datasets.

Comment: Theoretically both has to be trained on Imagenet dataset as specified in documentation...

Answer (score 1):

Both `tf.keras.applications.ResNet50V2` and `hub.KerasLayer` for `ResNet50V2` are trained on the same image_net dataset and share the same weights, there is no difference between both.

Coming to the accuracy difference, I have tried both the API's to load base model and run on 10 epochs.
I saw a minor difference in the accuracy of both training and validation.
Then again after running the TensorFlow hub base model for the second time, again I found some minor change in accuracy.This may be due to the order of calculation of these and also could be floating point precision error.

Below are the outputs:

**tf.keras.applications.ResNet50V2 as base model.**

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50V2(input_shape=(96, 96, 3), include_top=False, weights='imagenet', pooling='avg')
base_model.trainable = False

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  base_model,
  Dense(10, activation='softmax')
]) 
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer="adam",metrics=["accuracy"])
H = model.fit_generator(aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=16),
    validation_data=(testX, testY), steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // 16,
    epochs=10)
```

**Output 1:**

```
Epoch 1/10
103/103 [==============================] - 55s 535ms/step - loss: 1.5820 - accuracy: 0.4789 - val_loss: 0.9162 - val_accuracy: 0.6949
Epoch 2/10
103/103 [==============================] - 57s 554ms/step - loss: 0.9539 - accuracy: 0.6534 - val_loss: 0.8376 - val_accuracy: 0.6852
Epoch 3/10
103/103 [==============================] - 55s 532ms/step - loss: 0.8610 - accuracy: 0.6944 - val_loss: 0.7104 - val_accuracy: 0.7240
Epoch 4/10
103/103 [==============================] - 55s 533ms/step - loss: 0.7671 - accuracy: 0.7214 - val_loss: 0.5988 - val_accuracy: 0.7918
Epoch 5/10
103/103 [==============================] - 55s 536ms/step - loss: 0.6994 - accuracy: 0.7526 - val_loss: 0.6029 - val_accuracy: 0.7676
Epoch 6/10
103/103 [==============================] - 55s 537ms/step - loss: 0.6880 - accuracy: 0.7508 - val_loss: 0.6121 - val_accuracy: 0.7724
Epoch 7/10
103/103 [==============================] - 55s 533ms/step - loss: 0.6588 - accuracy: 0.7593 - val_loss: 0.5486 - val_accuracy: 0.8015
Epoch 8/10
103/103 [==============================] - 55s 534ms/step - loss: 0.6640 - accuracy: 0.7630 - val_loss: 0.5287 - val_accuracy: 0.8232
Epoch 9/10
103/103 [==============================] - 54s 528ms/step - loss: 0.6004 - accuracy: 0.7881 - val_loss: 0.4598 - val_accuracy: 0.8426
Epoch 10/10
103/103 [==============================] - 55s 530ms/step - loss: 0.5583 - accuracy: 0.8016 - val_loss: 0.4605 - val_accuracy: 0.8426
```

**Tensorflow Hub as base model.**

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42) 
base_model =hub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v2_50/feature_vector/4', input_shape=(96, 96, 3))
base_model.trainable = False

model = tf.keras.Sequential([base_model ,Dense(10, activation='softmax')]) 
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer="adam",metrics=["accuracy"])
H = model.fit_generator(aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=16),
    validation_data=(testX, testY), steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // 16,
    epochs=10)
```

**Output 2:**

```
Epoch 1/10
103/103 [==============================] - 54s 526ms/step - loss: 1.7543 - accuracy: 0.4464 - val_loss: 1.0185 - val_accuracy: 0.5981
Epoch 2/10
103/103 [==============================] - 53s 519ms/step - loss: 0.9827 - accuracy: 0.6283 - val_loss: 1.0067 - val_accuracy: 0.6416
Epoch 3/10
103/103 [==============================] - 56s 548ms/step - loss: 0.8719 - accuracy: 0.6944 - val_loss: 0.7195 - val_accuracy: 0.7240
Epoch 4/10
103/103 [==============================] - 54s 521ms/step - loss: 0.8177 - accuracy: 0.7208 - val_loss: 0.7490 - val_accuracy: 0.7385
Epoch 5/10
103/103 [==============================] - 54s 522ms/step - loss: 0.7641 - accuracy: 0.7379 - val_loss: 0.6325 - val_accuracy: 0.7797
Epoch 6/10
103/103 [==============================] - 54s 523ms/step - loss: 0.6551 - accuracy: 0.7655 - val_loss: 0.6431 - val_accuracy: 0.7579
Epoch 7/10
103/103 [==============================] - 55s 530ms/step - loss: 0.6538 - accuracy: 0.7734 - val_loss: 0.5824 - val_accuracy: 0.7797
Epoch 8/10
103/103 [==============================] - 55s 536ms/step - loss: 0.6387 - accuracy: 0.7691 - val_loss: 0.6254 - val_accuracy: 0.7772
Epoch 9/10
103/103 [==============================] - 56s 540ms/step - loss: 0.6394 - accuracy: 0.7685 - val_loss: 0.6539 - val_accuracy: 0.7554
Epoch 10/10
103/103 [==============================] - 55s 536ms/step - loss: 0.5816 - accuracy: 0.7955 - val_loss: 0.5703 - val_accuracy: 0.7990
```

Now if I run the Tensorflow hub model again.

**Output 3:**

```
Epoch 1/10
103/103 [==============================] - 55s 534ms/step - loss: 1.6412 - accuracy: 0.4764 - val_loss: 1.0697 - val_accuracy: 0.5738
Epoch 2/10
103/103 [==============================] - 54s 528ms/step - loss: 1.0312 - accuracy: 0.6412 - val_loss: 1.0196 - val_accuracy: 0.6077
Epoch 3/10
103/103 [==============================] - 59s 570ms/step - loss: 0.8710 - accuracy: 0.6975 - val_loss: 0.7088 - val_accuracy: 0.7240
Epoch 4/10
103/103 [==============================] - 54s 529ms/step - loss: 0.8108 - accuracy: 0.7128 - val_loss: 0.6539 - val_accuracy: 0.7458
Epoch 5/10
103/103 [==============================] - 54s 522ms/step - loss: 0.7311 - accuracy: 0.7440 - val_loss: 0.6029 - val_accuracy: 0.7676
Epoch 6/10
103/103 [==============================] - 54s 523ms/step - loss: 0.6683 - accuracy: 0.7612 - val_loss: 0.6621 - val_accuracy: 0.7506
Epoch 7/10
103/103 [==============================] - 54s 527ms/step - loss: 0.6518 - accuracy: 0.7753 - val_loss: 0.6166 - val_accuracy: 0.7700
Epoch 8/10
103/103 [==============================] - 54s 524ms/step - loss: 0.6147 - accuracy: 0.7795 - val_loss: 0.5611 - val_accuracy: 0.7797
Epoch 9/10
103/103 [==============================] - 54s 522ms/step - loss: 0.6671 - accuracy: 0.7667 - val_loss: 0.5126 - val_accuracy: 0.8087
Epoch 10/10
103/103 [==============================] - 54s 525ms/step - loss: 0.6090 - accuracy: 0.7832 - val_loss: 0.6355 - val_accuracy: 0.7627
```

Hope this answeres your question.

Comment: No it is very different in my case: with tf-hub pretrained I reach 99% of accuracy after 50 epochs starting from 60% of accuracy. With "keras.applications" one it starts from 60% as well, on valid, and after 3 epochs it overfit and validation accuracy remain on 80%